# No se modifica tabla de MySql

Tags: php, mysql

Mi pregunta es bastante sencilla, estoy haciendo una modificación de un registro en mi tabla, pero llevo muchas horas viendo porque no funciona, se que es algo sencillo porque ya lo he hecho varias veces, espero que alguien me pueda ayudar a solucionarlo, tambien acepto recomendaciones  a mi código ya que se que no es el mejor.
El error que me marca es :
`Undefined variable Id on the line 14 in`modificar_historia.php
`La tabla se llama`tabla_imagen` y por lo pronto recorte mi modificar.php a solo un placeholder para ver si asi analizaba mejor mi codigo
La tabla tiene los siguientes campos, Id, nombre e Imagen, cuando modifico se imprime el echo de que si se modifico pero la tabla no se modifica

**MODIFICAR.PHP**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Registro de datos</title>

</head>

<body>
     <?php 
    include("conexion2.php");
    $Id = $_REQUEST['Id'];

    $query = "SELECT * FROM tabla_imagen WHERE Id ='$Id'";
    $resultado= $conexion->query($query);
    $row = $resultado->fetch_assoc();
    ?>
    <center>

    <form action="modificarh.php?id=<?php echo $row['Id']; ?>" method="post"  enctype="multipart/form-data">

 <input type="text" REQUIRED name="nombre" placeholder="Nombre..." value="<? 
  php echo $row['nombre'];?>"/><br/><br/>            
                <input type="submit" value="Guardar" >  
                </form>
             </center>
    </body> 
    </html>
```

**MODIFICARH.PHP**

```
<?php

include ("conexion2.php");

$Id = $_REQUEST['Id'];

$nombre = $_POST['nombre'];

$query = "UPDATE tabla_imagen SET nombre='$nombre' WHERE Id = '$Id'";
$resultado = $conexion->query($query);

if($resultado){


    header("Location: index.php");
}
else{
    echo "No se modiifico";
}

?>
```

Comment: Hola, no veo nada raro en la consulta, por lo pronto podrías poner un echo a tu variable $query, así la ves a ver con los datos, copia la consulta y correla en tu (supongo) phpmyadmin. Como no nos has indicado la tabla el error puede ser que tu variable **Id** no se llame como la tienes en tu consulta

Comment: La tabla tiene los siguientes campos Id, nombre e Imagen, enseguida lo agrego a la pregunta, en efecto uso phpmyadmin, gracias por las recomendaciones.

Comment: El problema era que las variables no estaban bien concatenadas ;)

Answer (score 1):

El error que veo en tu codigo es el siguiente.
En el action de tu formulario el parametro `id`

```
<form action="modificarh.php?id=<?php echo $row['Id']; ?>" method="post"  enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Y en el controlador esperas `Id` y este al no tener valor, no ejecutara tu update, en estricto rigor si lo hará pero no actualizará nada.

Habria que cambiar

```
$Id = $_REQUEST['Id'];
```

Por

```
$Id = $_REQUEST['id'];
```

Saludos,

Answer (score 1):

Estas utilizando el method POST en el metodo de envio a tu archivo MODIFICAR.PHP
Al momento en el que utilizas las etiquetas < form > debes identificar los datos que se van a enviar y todos ellos deben ir dentro de las etiquetas.
Normalmente se utiliza un input tipo hidden

```
<input type="hidden" name="Id" value="'.$row['Id'].'" />
```

En MODIFICAR.PHP
Ya existiria el dato en el post del documento
y podrias obtenerlo mediante POST o REQUEST

```
$Id = $_POST['Id'];
$Id = $_REQUEST['Id'];
```